# Displacement sensors for car wheel and datasheets

Tags: suspension, car

Probably title says it all, but I am on my design work for car suspension and cannot find a good displacement sensor for each of the wheels of the car. I tried to look up for accelerometers, which can tell tilting of the overall car from 4 directions, but it is hard to get the actual displacement mathematically.

Also looked for Electro-Optical proximity Detectors, but cannot find any data-sheets with proper explanations or any products in practice.

All I need is displacement detector/sensor, which could withstand car road vibrations (robust), would have high accuracy and sensitivity and would supply me with the sensitivity output information such as Volts/centimetre or similar. From this info I should be able to do my mathematics!

Thanks everyone for your time. 
All suggestions are welcome ad I will be happy to look for answers where you will point me. Tried Google countless times :(

Comment: What do you mean by "displacement" ... you trying to find a distance with it? Not sure I understand.

Comment: So you want a sensor to measure the distance the suspension is being compressed in real time?

Comment: Tell us what you want to know rather than how you are trying to solve it. :)

Comment: JPHI1618, you're are correct. I want to measure how much my suspension is displaced, so I could supply with extra force

Comment: I want to supply or remove extra force dependent on cars oscillations when it hits a road disturbance. To do that I need a sensor to measure a suspension displacement (compression) or distance change from ground to the car body set point. I know both techniques use different  sensors, but I think both could be used in same manner. Sorry for missing that in post before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is called a *ride height sensor*.  [Delphi](http://www.delphi.com/manufacturers/auto/sensors/chassis) is one manufacturer that makes sensors for a wide variety of production vehicles from Corvettes to Cadillacs.

[image: Delphi rotary sensor]

For motorsports applications, there are also optical sensors.  One popular one (at least in pro racing) is [KA Sensors RHL3](http://www.kasensors.com/us/products/non-contact).  It bounces a laser beam off the ground and determines height.  As I recall the Porsche factory cars that won at Le Mans in 2015 used them.

[image: KA Sensors RHL3 laser sensor]

Depending on your exact needs, using the term "ride height sensor" should get you plenty of hits in the search engine of your choice.